# Explanation needed about linq queries

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private bedrijf_modelDataContext dc = new bedrijf_modelDataContext();

public IList<Afdeling> selectAll()
{ 
    var result = from a in dc.Afdelings
        select a;
    return result.ToList();
}
```

This code is supposed to return all the records from the Afdeling-table.
This code works, but it comes from my teacher, and there is no explanation whatsoever as to how this works. Can somebody explain what this exactly does? Thank you.

Comment: Pls read this when you have time. This will give you a good idea about LINQ to SQL http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private bedrijf_modelDataContext dc = new bedrijf_modelDataContext();
```

Creates a DataContext. Think of it as a workspace + database connection. It tracks the loaded entities.

```
var result = from a in dc.Afdelings
    select a;
```

Is a Linq query that retreives the records as objects. In this case everything from the table. The query is not executed immediately, Linq has 'deferred execution'.

```
 return result.ToList();
```

The ToList() fetches all the records (counters the deferred execution).